# OpenWnnをAndroid Studioでビルドしたい

Tags: android, android-studio

openwnnのソースをダウンロードしたのですが、Android Studioでビルドすることができなくて困っています。有識者のかたぜひアドバイスをください。

私が使っているソースは以下の手順でダウンロードしたものをAndroid Studioのインポート (ソースがEclipseのもののため) 機能でインポートしたものです。

```
$ git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/inputmethods/OpenWnn.git
$ cd OpenWnn
$ git tag
$ git branch -a
$ git checkout -b ics-mr1-release origin/ics-mr1-release
```

エラーメッセージに

```
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/jp.co.omronsoft.openwnn
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_VERSION_DOWNGRADE]
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm uninstall jp.co.omronsoft.openwnn
DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR
```

というメッセージが出てくるのですが、具体的にどうしたらいいかわかりません。宜しくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

エラーメッセージの内容自体は「インストール済みのアプリよりも古いバージョン（VersionCode）をアップデートしようとしている」というものなのですが、そもそもこのプロジェクトのAndroidManifest.xmlにはVersionCodeが書かれていないので、実際は「ビルドしたアプリのVersionCodeが分からないのでインストールができない」という意味で出ているものだと思います。

とりあえずAndroid Studio用のプロジェクトに変換済みであれば、`app/build.gradle`の`defaultConfig`内にversionCodeとversionNameを追記することで、このエラーは解決できるかと思います。

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "jp.co.omronsoft.openwnn"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0" // versionNameは不要かもしれません
}
```

で、ここから本題なのですが、AVD（エミュレータ）の場合、端末内の読み込み専用領域の中にOpenWnnがすでにインストールされているらしく、上記の対応を行っても次は「電子署名が異なる」というエラーでインストールできません。

https://sites.google.com/site/cobproducts/home/android/development/sdk-emuappuninstall
上記サイトでは、インストール済みのOpenWnnのやり方が書かれていますが、自分の方で試してもroot権限が上手く取得できず、解決できませんでした。

そのため、OpenWnnがデフォルトでインストールされていない実機やGenymotionを使った方が良さそうです。自分は実機のNexus6でインストールまでの確認はできました。

Comment: defaultConfigについてくわしく教えていただきありがとうございました。
大変参考になり、問題としていたエラーは解決できました。

実際の動作なのですが、yamacraftさんのないようと、こちらの記事（http://shekeenlab.hatenablog.com/entry/2014/09/15/000110）を参考に教え通り実機（nexus7初代）でねばったのですが、ビルドはとおりますが、実施に実行するとエラー終了する状態どまりになっています。

ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

メーカー純正のapkは上手く出来ないかも知れません(インストールのちょっとした工夫すれば良いかも)。

ですが、Genymotionを使うと一部のアプリが使えるようです。